# VBA sorting a range with no hardcoding

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

I am trying to sort a range of cells without hardcoding the starting and stopping points. My range will always start in column A and span to column M, however the rows it stops and starts on will vary. I figured out how to set a variable and incorporate it into the Range function for the last-row, but I can't figure out how to do that for the row the range should start on. Here is my code so far:

```
Range("A6:M" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("A6"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

This works only if I start my range on row 6. What I can't figure out is how to tell excel to start my range on the first row that is not blank in column A.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you need to update the `Range("A6:M")` portion? Something like `Range("A" & startRow & ":M" & lastRow).Sort ...`

Comment: You the man! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Determine if A1 is blank. Use A1 if not blank and the [ctrl]+[down] if it is blank.

```
dim startRow as long, lastRow as long
With worksheets("sheet1")
    lastRow = .cells(.rows.count, "M").end(xlup).row
    if isempty(.cells(1, "A") then
        startrow = .cells(1, "A").end(xldown).row
    else
        startRow = 1
    end if
    with .range(.cells(startrow, "A"), .cells(lastrow, "M"))
        .cells.Sort Key1:=.cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    end with
end with
```